# Why is my htaccess line being overruled

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server, url-rewriting

I have a cms that has the following path: cms/administrator/index.php

I've made the following line to redirect to this whilst only typing /cms after my site url.

```
#CMS rewrite
RewriteRule ^cms/$ /cms/administrator/index.php [L]
```

But this line doesn't rewrite to my index file in my cms folder, it redirects to catlisting.php a line which is added a few lines later:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ catlisting.php?alias=$1 [QSA,L]
```

How come it uses this rule when typing: website.nl/cms ?

This is my entire htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

#Indexes uitzetten
Options -Indexes

#Cross site access toestaan
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"

#Sitename

DirectoryIndex index.php

#CMS rewrite
RewriteRule ^cms/$ /cms/administrator/index.php [L]

RewriteRule         ^home index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule         ^overzicht shopping-cart-page.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule         ^bestellen checkout.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule         ^contact contact.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule         ^vragen vragen.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule         ^status success.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule         ^voorwaarden voorwaard.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule         ^info/(.*).html contentlisting.php?alias=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule         ^verhuur/(.*)/ lp.php?alias=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule         ^(.*).html content.php?alias=$1 [QSA,L]
#Zorg ervoor dat onderstaande regels alleen worden uitgevoerd als het geen folder (d) is of een file (f)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#LP
RewriteRule ^c-[^/]+/(.+)$ /verhuur/$1 [L,R=301]
#Shop
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ product-page.php?cat=$1&alias=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ catlisting.php?alias=$1 [QSA,L]

#ErrorPages
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error/500.php
ErrorDocument 501 /error/501.php
ErrorDocument 503 /error/503.php
ErrorDocument 504 /error/504.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the traling  slash in your `cms` rule pattern `^cms/$` . Your pattern matches `cms` uri with with a traling slash  ( `/cms/` )  and it fails to match `/cms` (without a traling slash) .

Your `/cms` uri is getting rewritten to `catlisting.php?alias=$1` because last rule has a catch all pattern with an optional traling slash `^([\w-]+)/?$` which matches both `/cms` and `/cms/` .

To fix this, you need to remove the traling slash from your `cms` Rewrite pattern

```
RewriteRule ^cms$ /cms/administrator/index.php [L]
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thanks.